# Issue with the Azure File Copy on VM

Tags: azure, gitlab-auto-devops

I am trying to copy my files to my virtual machine using Azure File copy tas in my release definition and I am getting the following error :-

Could not fetch access token for Managed Identity. Please configure Managed Identity for virtual machine 'https://aka.ms/azure-msi-docs'. Status code: '400', Error message: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Identity not found"}
2019-02-02T13:55:58.2715077Z ##[section]Finishing: AzureVMs File Copy copy

I tried multiple things but still not able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful if you list the multiple things you have tried.
However, the error is fairly clear, when you create a task to work with Azure you need to provide a service principal via the Azure DevOps connection object, that has access to your subscription and VM. The error message indicates that this account cannot be found.

You either need to update your connection with an account that exists and has access or if your build agent is running in Azure, configure it with managed identity and grant that access.